# onResponse return variable or throw exception Retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, php, retrofit2

I have a problem with my code.

I would like to return a variable or an exception but I don't understand the method in the different post in Stack Overflow.

I'm new with retrofit if someone can explain to me a solution, it's for a project.

I use this instance method in the class `User`, it's my model in the MVC.

I would like to return a boolean variable when my user is created and an exception if the connection is down.

```java
public void connectPassword(String nameuser, String password) {
  Api api = new Api();
  Call < Connection > call = api.getService().connectPassWord(nameuser, password);
  call.enqueue(new Callback < Connection > () {
    public void onResponse(Call < Connection > call, Response < Connection > response) {
      System.out.println(response.body().getToken());
      System.out.println("Connecter");
      User.this.token = response.body().getToken();
      //return boolean her 
    }

    public void onFailure(Call < Connection > call, Throwable throwable) {
      System.out.print(throwable.getMessage());
      // throw Exception her
    }
  });
}


My class ApiService

public interface ApiService {

  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("createuser.php")
  Call < Register > sendRegister(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, @Field("email") String email);

  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("login.php")
  Call < Connection > connectPassWord(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("login.php")
  Call < Connection > connectToken(@Field("username") String username, @Field("token") String password);

}
```

And my class `Api`:

```java
public class Api {

  private Retrofit retrofit;
  private ApiService service;

  public Api() {
    this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://localhost/ProjetS2/").addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    this.service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
  }

  public ApiService getService() {
    return this.service;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can make use of interfaces, have you tried that?

Comment: I did though they run on Retrofit's thread, which can't act in my controller on JavaFX one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
public void connectPassword(String nameuser, String password, MyInterface myInterface) {
    Api api = new Api();
    Call<Connection> call = api.getService().connectPassWord(nameuser, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Connection>() {
        public void onResponse(Call<Connection> call, Response<Connection> response) {
            System.out.println(response.body().getToken());
            System.out.println("Connecter");
            User.this.token = response.body().getToken();
            myInterface.onSuccess(true);
            //return boolean her 
        }

        public void onFailure(Call<Connection> call, Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.print(throwable.getMessage());
            myInterface.onException(throwable.getMessage());
            // throw Exception her
        }
    });
}
```

**MyInterface.class**

```
public interface MyInterface{
public void onSuccess(boolean value);
public void onException(String value);
}
```

**From your calling class Suppose Main**

```
public class Main implements MyInterface{

@Override
public void onSuccess(boolean value){
//TODO do your stuff with returned boolean from your call
}

@Override
public void onException(String value){
//TODO you will receive the message here
}

//in your onCreate
...
//method call
connectPassword("username","password",this);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect i have make something similar, and this work perfectly
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't simply return from retrofit callbacks. They're asynchronous and therefore you'll get your values asynchronously too.

What you can do however, is propagate the value up with your own callbacks. This will lead to the so called "callback hell", but it works and if you're not too bothered by it it'll be fine.

So let me try and walk you through a possible solution (there are several ways you can do this).

Say you have your callback defined like so:

```
public interface UserCallbacks {
   void onUserCreatedSuccessfully(@NonNull User user);

   void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable);
}
```

Very simple interface that exposes 2 methods that you can call. First one tells the listener the user was successfully created and the other tells the listener there was an error.

Now you change your method to something like this:

```
public void connectPassword(String nameuser, String password, UserCallbacks callbacks) {
   Api api = new Api();
   Call<Connection> call = api.getService().connectPassWord(nameuser, password);
   call.enqueue(new Callback<Connection>() {
    public void onResponse(Call<Connection> call, Response<Connection> response) {
        callbacks.onUserCreatedSuccessfully(/*send the user here*/);
    }

    public void onFailure(Call<Connection> call, Throwable throwable) {
        callbacks.onError(throwable);
    }
   });
}
```

The last step is to pass the callbacks object. Say your controller implements the callbacks interface, you could do it like this:

```
public class UserController implements UserCallbacks {
  // ...
  public void onUserCreatedSuccessfully(@NonNull User user) {
     // do whatever we need to do
  }

  public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
     // inspect the error and see what we have to change in the ui
  }

  public void connect(String username, String password) {
     // Suppose you have your service created
     service.connectPassword(username, password. this);
  }
}
```

Just make sure you run any UI code in the UI thread. Can use [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))